# How to check if table is empty during metadata lock in mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, locking, table-locking

I need to maintain ping service that has to check if particular table is empty every 20 seconds. However, from time to time a script performs work on that table which results in metadata lock. This script can sometimes run for hours. This results in ping requests falling into "waiting for metadata lock" state and piling up very fast. Sometimes this results in "too many connections" error.

My question is: is there a way to check if table is empty, that does not care if there is a lock? If not, what other solutions are possible?

I am using Rails 3.2 with RDS mysql.